Excel: Single Bar graph with multiple sub data
I am trying to figure out if there is a way to plot data in a single bar graph.
For eg my data is



config
Value




c1
18


c2
24


c3
63


c4
94


max
125




Something like the picture above.
Edit: added table instead raw data

Can you put your sample data into a table and share with us what you have tried? Excel's chart options are pretty easy to look at and try, and there's good explanations in the app telling you the type of data that works for different charts.

How to Make a Stacked Bar Chart in Excel With Multiple Data?

Here's where you can generate a good table for this site
